# datagridview keypress event for adding new row

Tags: c#, datagridview, row, keypress

i have a datagridview that has 6 column, i want to add a new row every time i press "Tab" button (only) on the last cell of the column, i used the code bellow to prevent adding row everytime i write cell value

```
dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
```

i have already use keypress event on cell[5] (last cell) but it does not work,
last cell was set to read only

```
private void dataGridView1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 5)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Tab)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
        }
    }
}
```

thanks for your time, sorry about my english anyway

Comment: Try chancing it to: dataGridView1.Rows.Add(new DataGridViewRow());

Comment: What do you mean by "it does not work last cell was set to read only"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will add a `Row` if and only if the current cell is the last one in the `DGV` and the user presses `Tab`.

(Note that (obviously) the user now can't tab out of the `DGV`, except by **backtabbing** over the first cell..)

```
int yourLastColumnIndex = dataGridView.Columns.Count - 1;

protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    if (dataGridView.Focused && keyData == Keys.Tab) &&
        if (dataGridView.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == yourLastColumnIndex
            dataGridView.CurrentRow.Index == dataGridView.RowCount - 1)
        {
            dataGridView.Rows.Add();
            // we could return true; here to suppress the key
            // but we really want to move on into the new row..!
        }

    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

Any attempt to use any of the Key events of the `DGV` will eventually **leave** the `DGV` instead of adding a `Row`..